# retrieve value in selectbox in struts2

Tags: java, struts2

```
package vaannila;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class RegisterAction extends ActionSupport {

    private String userName;

    private String password;

    private String gender;

    private String about;

    private String country;

    private ArrayList<Country> countryList;

    private String[] community;

    private ArrayList<String> communityList;

    private Boolean  mailingList;

    public String populate() {

        countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
        countryList.add(new Country(1, "India"));
        countryList.add(new Country(2, "USA"));
        countryList.add(new Country(3, "France"));

        communityList = new ArrayList<String>();
        communityList.add("Java");
        communityList.add(".Net");
        communityList.add("SOA");

        community = new String[]{"Java",".Net"};
        mailingList = true;

        return "populate";
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getAbout() {
        return about;
    }

    public void setAbout(String about) {
        this.about = about;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public ArrayList<Country> getCountryList() {
        return countryList;
    }

    public void setCountryList(ArrayList<Country> countryList) {
        this.countryList = countryList;
    }

    public String[] getCommunity() {
        return community;
    }

    public void setCommunity(String[] community) {
        this.community = community;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getCommunityList() {
        return communityList;
    }

    public void setCommunityList(ArrayList<String> communityList) {
        this.communityList = communityList;
    }

    public Boolean getMailingList() {
        return mailingList;
    }

    public void setMailingList(Boolean mailingList) {
        this.mailingList = mailingList;
    }

}
```

**index.jsp**

```
      <s:select name="country" list="countryList" listKey="countryId"
    listValue="countryName" headerKey="0" headerValue="Country"
    label="Select a country" />
```

**success.jsp**

```
        Country: <s:property value="country" /><br>
```

When I select a value in textbox,it is retrieving id and not name i.e when I select india I am getting 1 instead of India.

Is there any way to retrieve name instead of id?

Comment: Please show your complete action and jsp.  I don't see an attribute in the action for countryName at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the arrayList communityList must be declared of type Country not String

```
private ArrayList<Country> communityList;
```

make sure it has **getter method** in the action class

Then use the following syntax in the jsp

```
   <s:iterator value="countryList"> <!-- here myList contains the list of objects -
     <s:property value="countryName" /><br/>
     <s:property value="countryId" /><br/>
   </s:iterator>
```

As per your edited question you need to use countryName as the listKey

```
<s:select name="country" list="countryList" listKey="countryName" listValue="countryName" headerKey="0" headerValue="Country" label="Select country" />
```

Comment: i have edited my question actually i want selectbox value to be displayed.....not id.

Comment: In order to get country name as key you need to declare countryName as listKey in the select tag.`<s:select name="country" list="countryList" listKey="countryName"
    listValue="countryName" headerKey="0" headerValue="Country"
    label="Select a country" />`

Comment: IF i am doing this i am getting 1,2,3 as values in drop down rather than India ,USA

Comment: dont change the listValue, let it be countryName only

Comment: yes ,it worked,thks but i didnt understand the logic.in <s:property vale=country/> i am calling getCountry().what is the use of listVale and Key.can  give expaination

Comment: Suppose you have a list of users in which you want to show the names of the users but you want to submit their email on selecting a name in that case listKey wd be userEmail and listValue wd be userName.This is a common scenario where you give a list of names to end users and submit email address to the server

Comment: that is listKey will hold the vale submitted to server,which will be retrieved further.

Comment: then what is the use of calling getCountry() method.can i delcare CountryName property in action and get the value from there by calling getter method

Comment: It is because countryName is a property of Country object. getCountryName() will be internally called by anyway.You can put a breakpoint to see this caaling

Comment: k thks u so much.Can u suggest me a book to learn struts2.tutorials are not descriptive.

Comment: I have not read any book but i guess [these](http://www.amazon.com/Struts-Design-Programming-Tutorial/dp/0980331609) are the good ones. I agree that struts2 documentation available on the net is not good enough, i have spent lot of time experimenting and searching

Comment: honestly i dont know, but one of my friend reads [this one](http://www.infibeam.com/Books/info/sharanam-shahvaishali-shah/struts-2-beginners-book-cd-rom/9788184046656.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a public getter for countryList. If it is still not working then see if 6 `<br/>` are getting printed in the output to verify whether the loop itself is running or not. Also check for any exceptions in your console.